# Request: Clever Things to do with Naive Bayes

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes, weka

I am trying to drive up the performance of a Naive Bayes classifier, and I haven't been having terribly much luck. I've been working in Weka, but have enough knowledge of R to (possibly) implement some techniques that aren't in that tool. The metric I'm focusing on is area under the ROC curve, which I've been able to bring up from 0.57 to 0.61, but would like to boost to at least 0.65. Here are some of the particulars:

The data set has ~20000 instances, about 5% of which are positive and the remainder of which are negative. Currently, it's split into 65% train/35% test so that I can do things like resampling without polluting my test sample.

The data set originally consisted of 28 attributes and a single binary class. I have since removed all but 10 attributes, which has brought the performance up by about 0.025. Most attributes are nominal and have only a few dozen possible values, but some are numeric (integers only, with a small range), and one nominal attribute has a few hundred different levels.

Resampling the data (with replacement, and with bias towards a uniform class) dramatically shifts the type of errors (far more false positives and true positives), but bumps up the AUC values by about 0.005.

Adding cluster labels based on the results of expectation-maximization clustering hasn't proven useful, nor has splitting the training and test sets into different subsets based on those labels and training separate classifiers for each cluster.

Any suggestions that you can offer are welcome, any requests for clarification likewise. Thank you!

Comment: This seems likely to be too open-ended & fuzzy to yield good answers here. People may vote to close this question as well. You may want to see if you can focus your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Okay a few things.

- naive Bayes per se is not necessarily known for its good performance.
- The main reasons why naive Bayes is still used nowadays is that it can outperform "more powerful" alternatives if the sample sizes are small [1]
- Another thing why naive Bayes is still popular is that it is very, very fast to train (also very compatible to on-line learning)

[1]   Pedro Domingos and Michael Pazzani. On the optimality of the simple bayesian classifier under zero-one loss. Machine learning, 29(2-3):103–130, 1997.

Which performance metric you use is up to your task. It may be accuracy, ROC auc, F1, precision, recall ...

An auc of 0.57 to 0.61 would suggest that your classifier is only slightly better than random guessing. That's unfortunate... But it might also have sth to do with your extreme imbalance in your training data.

Have you tried 10-fold stratified cross-validation for evaluation on the training set for feature selection, dimensionality reduction, and hyperparameter optimization? I.e, precision, recall, F1. Or confusion matrices would also be interesting to see what's going on.

Btw. if you are interested, I have some resources on naive Bayes with further references that could be helpful: 
[Naive Bayes and Text Classification I
- Introduction and Theory](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_naive_bayes_1.html)
And here a music-lyrics classifier that is build upon a naive Bayes model: 
https://github.com/rasbt/musicmood